# Screen goes blank or to low resolution on mode changes

Tags: troubleshooting, display, graphics-card

Hardware:

- Gigabyte EX58-UD5 motherboard
- Gigabyte GTX260OC video card
- Samsung 245T monitor

When I turn this computer on one of the following things happen randomly:

- everything goes fine
- on a screen mode change (e.g. between the BIOS opening screen and the first graphical mode of Windows Vista boot or between the different graphic modes of Windows Vista boot) the screen is forced to a very low resolution (my guess is it is 640x480 in 16 colors)
- on a screen mode change the screen goes blank, it seems that the monitor doesn't get a video signal.

The monitor is connected to the video card by a DVI cable. If I replace either the monitor or the video card in the machine then everything works fine always. I also tried to replace the power supply because i thought the video card doesn't get enough power but it didn't help either.

What should I try to debug this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a VGA cable instead (assuming graphics card and monitor support that)?

Comment: The video card have only DVI outputs. But I tried to replace the cable and it didn't help.

Comment: Most video cards that don't have a VGA jack at least put the VGA signal through the DVI jack, but you need an adapter for that. Even then, of course, that would be just a small debugging step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/VGA/BIOS_DownloadFile.aspx?FileType=BIOS&FileID=14946

This new VGA BIOS from Gigabyte solved the problem.